# Is it possible to add inline styling to a React component by using a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm new to React and I come from an Angular background where all we have is classes. 
I'm now trying to figure out if I can add styling to my html when using a class.

The React docs (regarding [Drawers](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#drawer)) are using a function to create the component. But I'm used to using classes instead of functions.

So question, is it possible to add styling to the element with the way I'm trying it now (and in a class)?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    list: {
      width: 250,
    }
});

export default class NavBar extends Component<any, any> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { open: false };
    }

    // Will complain about this
    readonly classes = useStyles();

    render() { 
        return (
            <div className={this.classes.list}>test</div>
        )
    }
}
```

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
>   of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
>   reasons: 
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app 
>   See ... for tips about how to debug and
>   fix this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can define inline styling in react using style object.

```
const useStyles = {
  list: {
    width: 250,
    color: 'red'
  }
};
class NavBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { open: false };
  }
  render() { 
      return (
          <div style={useStyles.list}>test</div>
      )
  }
}
```